# getOwnPropertyDescriptor of redefined toString should be undefined

Tags: javascript, html, inheritance, prototype, prototypejs

I have redefined `toString` of `HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toDataURL`. When I am getting property descriptor of `toString` it should return `undefined`, but it returns the function. Any ideas how to fix it?

You can execute code here https://jsfiddle.net/nqk50a8r/

```
Object.defineProperty(HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toDataURL, 'toString', {
    value: function () { return 'function toDataURL() { [native code] }';}
});

var desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toDataURL, 'toString');

console.log(desc === undefined);
```

If you removed `defineProperty` block you will see that it returns `undefined`.

I redefined `toDataURL` by next code:

```
Object.defineProperty(HTMLCanvasElement.prototype, 'toDataURL', {
    value: function () { return 'new valu' }
});
```

If I didn't redefine `toString` it will return code itself when call `toString`.

Comment: Why should it be `undefined`? Every own property has a descriptor.

Comment: @CertainPerformance If you remove `defineProperty` block you will see that it returns `undefined`. So it's easy to track that toString was redefined.

Comment: If you're going to add a property that didn't exist before, there's no way to hide that from code that wants to check it out - they can see the descriptor

Comment: But the property exists, if you execute `HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toDataURL.toString()` it returns you the value. Maybe I redefined the property in incorrect way?

Comment: Yes, the property exists, that's why the descriptor is *not* `undefined`

Comment: I have created an example, if you go here https://jsfiddle.net/brne05q2/ you can see, that when I didn't redefined `toString` the `getOwnPropertyDescriptor` returns `undefined` but the property is defined as it returns the value. Once I redefined `toString` the `getOwnPropertyDescriptor` doesn't return `undefined` any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toDataURL` does not have an *own* property `toString` by default. The `toString` method you get by referencing `HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toDataURL.toString` is prototypally inherited from `Function.prototype.toString`:

```js
console.log(
  HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toDataURL.toString === Function.prototype.toString
);
```

No property exists directly on `HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toDataURL.toString`. But if you add one yourself, via

```
Object.defineProperty(HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toDataURL, 'toString',
```

then it *will* have such an own property, and will also log a property descriptor if you examine it.

If you want to monkeypatch your custom `toString` method while keeping `HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toDataURL.toString` empty, you can overwrite `Function.prototype.toString`.

Note that while this is technically possible, it's also very strange to do, and a bad idea to mutate built-in prototypes:

```
const origToString = Function.prototype.toString;
Function.prototype.toString = function() {
  if (this === HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toDataURL) return 'function toDataURL() { [native code] }';
  else return origToString.call(this);
}
```